# Acceder a funciones desde otro archivo en Python

Tags: python, funciones

Tengo una pregunta, y es que como podría acceder a otras funciones que estén en otros archivos, desde un archivo principal, donde las variables estén conectadas. Si es posible, me podrían dar un ejemplo? Gracias

Comment: Lo más parecido a lo que buscas es trabajar con objetos, tendrías tus clases en diferentes archivos con los métodos y atributos que requieras.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por la información

Comment: Importa el otro archivo con `import nombre` . No necesitas objetos para esto.

Comment: @abulafia mencionó que necesita que las variables estén conectadas, lo que me hace pensar que las variables de otros archivos se mantengan en memoria, usando solo modulos también se puede lograr eso ?

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como está explicado en el otro comentario, para usar la(s) funciones o código de otro archivo en tu trabajo actual, debes **importarlo**.

Debes tener en cuenta la **ubicación** en donde está el archivo del cual quieres usar sus funciones o código. Ejemplo: sí estoy trabajando en un proyecto, y todo está dentro de un solo directorio (carpeta), entonces tendría los siguientes archivos:

archivo_funciones.py #en este estarán las funciones que quieres usar
app.py #el archivo en donde quieres usar las funciones del otro archivo

En tu *app.py* debe estar en primera línea de código lo siguiente:

1. `import archivo_funciones`

De esa manera podrás usar las funciones, siempre y cuando antepongas el nombre del archivo para cada llamada de funciones (ejemplo: archivo_funciones.funcion_suma(1,2))

2. `from archivos_funciones import *`
   De esa manera importas todo el código del archivo funciones a tu *app.py*. En este no debes anteponer el nombre del archivo (ejemplo: funcion_suma(1,2))

Esas 2 son las más comunes y podrán solucionar tu problema, sin embargo, puedes ver las otras modos y ejemplos en la propia documentación Python: [Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a funciones desde otro fichero (módulo en python), sólo debes hacer el import y llamar a la función:

testA.py:

```py
def suma(A,B):
    return A + B
```

testB.py

```
import testA  # tienes varias formas de hacerlo, from testA import * (esto importa todas las funciones de testA, no es recomendable ya que si tienes funciones con el mismo nombre no sabrás de dónde es cada una), o from testA import suma

resultado = testA.suma(5, 3)  # si usaste alguna otra forma de import, puedes llamar la función directamente con resultado = suma(5, 3)
print(resultado)
```